# Knockout-Validation Using Regular Expression to Validate a Phone Number

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am trying to add a simple regular expression validation to one of my observables using Knockout-Validation.

I have the following:

```
self.ContactPhone = ko.observable().extend({
            required: true,
            pattern: {
                message: 'Invalid phone number.',
                params: '^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})$'
            }
        });
```

However, no matter what I enter, it returns the message 'Invalid phone number.' Is there a certain way I need to format the expression? I've tested it using purely JavaScript and it works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes otherwise javascript treats your one backslash itself as an escape-character for the next character. This is because this is a string and not a regexp literal.

Edit: Actually I just checked, and you can just use a regexp literal instead, so either of these would do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/ED3Mh/2/

```
self.ContactPhone = ko.observable().extend({
    required: true,
    pattern: {
        message: 'Invalid phone number.',
        params: /^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})$/            
    }
});
```

or:

```
params: '^\\D?(\\d{3})\\D?\\D?(\\d{3})\\D?(\\d{4})$'
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you dont have to use Regular Expression, here is the native way

```
self.ContactPhone = ko.observable().extend({ phoneUS : true });
```

More listed [here](http://mikedormitorio.azurewebsites.net/BlogPost/the-native-validation-rules-of-knockout-validation).

Comment: Do you know why `phoneUS` isn't listed on the official Knockout Validation website - https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules ?

Answer (score 0):

See the below working example in jsfiddle using regular expression that allows whitespace and + and() along with number following link

jsfiddle.net/JoelDerrick/f6g8npv6/1/